# node.js typescript project - heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm new in a programming world. I just fnished my very first app in typescript. I don't mengane with deploying it on hiroku. The proccess of compiling and using new tools I don't know makes it very coplicated. I read some articules, saw every yt tutorial I found and it didn’t help me. I suppose there is some problem with tsconfig configuration? I really don’t want that someone will waste his time to mange with it but maybe for someone of your who is more expirenced the solution will be simple. I already deployed on heroku standard node.js projects without any problems. I worked quite hard on my project so the fact that I can not delploy it, share it with my firends and add it portfolio makes me very furstrated. Thank you very much!

Btw. I know the project need some corretion (for example with public files but I will change it after I will manage with deployment).

github rep: https://github.com/sextus-empiricus/ts-arena

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2018",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom.iterable", "dom"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ts_w4_d5_arena",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "postinstall": "npm run build && mv -i -v public dist/ && rm -v -rf src",
    "deploy": "git add . && git commit -m Heroku && git push heroku master",
    "start:dev": "nodemon server.ts -e ts,js,scss,hbs",
    "sass:dev": "node-sass -rw public/sass/ -o public/styles",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "dateformat": "^5.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.4.2"
  }
}
```

hiroku building log:

```
[master c462aa5] Heroku
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 287 bytes | 287.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/nodejs
remote:        2. zidizei/typescript
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.4.2
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.4.2...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.4.2...
remote:        Using default npm version: 7.18.1
remote:        
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        > ts_w4_d5_arena@1.0.0 postinstall
remote:        > npm run build && mv -i -v public dist/ && rm -v -rf src
remote:
remote:        
remote:        > ts_w4_d5_arena@1.0.0 build
remote:        > tsc
remote:
remote:        mv: overwrite 'dist/public'? 
remote:        added 435 packages, and audited 436 packages in 16s
remote:
remote:        34 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        
remote:        > ts_w4_d5_arena@1.0.0 build
remote:        > tsc
remote:
remote:        
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 92 packages in 1s
remote:
remote:        4 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> TypeScript app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating build environment
remote: 
remote: -----> Development dependencies already installed
remote: 
remote: -----> Building application with tsc 4.6.2
remote:        Using configuration at /tmp/build_3231046f/tsconfig.json
remote:        app.ts:2:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path' or its corresponding type declarations.
remote:
remote:        2 import {join} from 'path';
remote:                             ~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        app.ts:3:26 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modules/express/index.js' imp
licitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        3 import * as express from 'express';
remote:                                   ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        app.ts:4:31 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'cookie-parser'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modules/cookie-parser/i
ndex.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cookie-parser` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cookie-parser'; 
remote:
remote:        4 import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
remote:                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        app.ts:5:29 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'body-parser'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modules/body-parser/index
.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/body-parser` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'body-parser';`    
remote:
remote:        5 import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
remote:                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        app.ts:17:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
remote:
remote:        17 app.use(express.static(join(__dirname + '/public')));
remote:                                       ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        app.ts:18:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.
remote:
remote:        18 app.use(express.static(join(__dirname + '/dist/public/js'))) //compiled ts for front:
remote:                                       ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        classes/class_Warrior.ts:1:26 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'uuid'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modules/uuid/d
ist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/uuid` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'uuid';`
remote:
remote:        1 import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';
remote:                                   ~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        controllers/controller_auth.ts:2:47 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modul
es/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        2 import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
remote:                                                        ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        controllers/controller_auth.ts:3:23 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'bcryptjs'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modu
les/bcryptjs/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bcryptjs';`
remote:
remote:        3 import {compare} from 'bcryptjs';
remote:                                ~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        controllers/controller_views.ts:1:33 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modu
les/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        1 import {Request, Response} from 'express';
remote:                                          ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        controllers/controller_warrios.ts:1:33 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_mo
dules/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        1 import {Request, Response} from 'express';
remote:                                          ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/db.ts:1:16 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/no
de`.
remote:
remote:        1 const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise'); // - ❗ wersja promisowa;
remote:                         ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/db.ts:5:11 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/no
de`.
remote:
remote:        5     host: process.env.DB_HOST,
remote:                    ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/db.ts:6:11 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/no
de`.
remote:
remote:        6     user: process.env.DB_USER,
remote:                    ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/db.ts:7:11 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/no
de`.
remote:
remote:        7     port: process.env.DB_PORT,
remote:                    ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/db.ts:8:15 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/no
de`.
remote:
remote:        8     database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
remote:                        ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/db.ts:9:15 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/no
de`.
remote:
remote:        9     password: process.env.DB_PASS,
remote:                        ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:6:29 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'bcryptjs'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_module
s/bcryptjs/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/bcryptjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bcryptjs';`
remote:
remote:        6 import {hash, compare} from 'bcryptjs';
remote:                                      ~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:32:41 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
 --save-dev @types/node`.
remote:
remote:        32         await pool.query(`INSERT INTO ${process.env.DB_TABLES_WARRIORS} VALUES (:id, :name, :strength, :agility, :defence, :endurance, D
EFAULT, DEFAULT, :password);`, {
remote:                                                   ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:46:38 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
 --save-dev @types/node`.
remote:
remote:        46         await pool.execute(`UPDATE ${process.env.DB_TABLES_WARRIORS} SET wins = :wins WHERE id = :id;`, {
remote:                                                ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:54:41 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
 --save-dev @types/node`.
remote:
remote:        54         await pool.query(`DELETE FROM ${process.env.DB_TABLES_WARRIORS} WHERE id = :id`, {
remote:                                                   ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:60:60 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
 --save-dev @types/node`.
remote:
remote:        60         const results = (await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM ${process.env.DB_TABLES_WARRIORS};`))[0];
remote:                                                                      ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:67:60 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
 --save-dev @types/node`.
remote:
remote:        67         const results = (await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM ${process.env.DB_TABLES_WARRIORS} ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT 10`))[0];
remote:                                                                      ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:74:61 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
 --save-dev @types/node`.
remote:
remote:        74         const [result] = (await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM ${process.env.DB_TABLES_WARRIORS} WHERE id = :id;`, {
remote:                                                                       ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        db/records/record_Warrior.ts:81:41 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
 --save-dev @types/node`.
remote:
remote:        81         await pool.query(`DELETE FROM ${process.env.DB_TABLES_WARRIORS} WHERE id = :id;`, {
remote:                                                   ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.d.ts:1:23 - error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
remote:
remote:        1 /// <reference types="node" />
remote:                                ~~~~
remote:
remote:        node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.d.ts:7:15 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BufferEncoding'.
remote:
remote:        7     encoding: BufferEncoding;
remote:                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        node_modules/express-handlebars/types/index.d.ts:41:13 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BufferEncoding'.
remote:
remote:        41  encoding?: BufferEncoding;
remote:                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        node_modules/express-handlebars/types/index.d.ts:49:13 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BufferEncoding'.
remote:
remote:        49  encoding?: BufferEncoding;
remote:                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        node_modules/express-handlebars/types/index.d.ts:75:13 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BufferEncoding'.
remote:
remote:        75  encoding?: BufferEncoding;
remote:                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        public/js/utils/btnAudio.ts:5:28 - error TS2550: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'. Do you need to change your target l
ibrary? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2016' or later.
remote:
remote:        5     if ([...btn.classList].includes('is-playing')) {
remote:                                     ~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        routers/router_views.ts:1:25 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modules/expr
ess/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        1 import * as expres from 'express';
remote:                                  ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        routers/router_warriorsApi.ts:1:26 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_module
s/express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        1 import * as express from 'express';
remote:                                   ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        server.ts:2:29 - error TS2580: Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/n
ode`.
remote:
remote:        2 const port: number = Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000;
remote:                                      ~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        utils/catchAsync.ts:1:47 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modules/express/
index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        1 import {NextFunction, Request, Response} from 'express';
remote:                                                        ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:        utils/globalErrorHandler.ts:1:47 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'express'. '/tmp/build_3231046f/node_modules/
express/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
remote:        Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express';`
remote:
remote:        1 import {NextFunction, Request, Response} from 'express';
remote:                                                        ~~~~~~~~~
remote:
remote:
remote:        Found 36 errors in 15 files.
remote:
remote:        Errors  Files
remote:        6  app.ts:2
remote:        1  classes/class_Warrior.ts:1
remote:        2  controllers/controller_auth.ts:2
remote:        1  controllers/controller_views.ts:1
remote:        1  controllers/controller_warrios.ts:1
remote:        6  db/db.ts:1
remote:        8  db/records/record_Warrior.ts:6
remote:        2  node_modules/express-handlebars/dist/express-handlebars.d.ts:1
remote:        3  node_modules/express-handlebars/types/index.d.ts:41
remote:        1  public/js/utils/btnAudio.ts:5
remote:        1  routers/router_views.ts:1
remote:        1  routers/router_warriorsApi.ts:1
remote:        1  server.ts:2
remote:        1  utils/catchAsync.ts:1
remote:        1  utils/globalErrorHandler.ts:1
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 69.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v27
remote:        https://ts-arena.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/ts-arena.git
   3f2b77d..c462aa5  master -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

hopefully I succeed to deploy my app on Heroku. It required two changes:

1. moving types from devDependencies to dependencies,
2. adding "module": "CommonJS" it tsconfig file.

Point 2 brought some problems with frontend script files. Module "CommonJS" changes imports to require. I didn't know how to manage with that really, so I compiled frontend files manually and just put them as .js files in project. Maybe in feature I will learn how to solve it.

Thank you!